# CD with autorun.exe file

Tags: cd, autorun

Is there any way to make work a CD for windows (which contains a file autorun.exe)?
This CD should be use by a 5 year kid (educational), so I need something quite easy.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install?  It sounds like Windows-only software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use autorun directory from Ubuntu. If you want to use Ubuntu and use the CD you have 2 possible options (the 2nd is the easiest):

1. WINE and open the CD from WINE. Problem: you need to setup the CD to work with WINE. And the application you want to use might not work with WINE. You can check the WINE [AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/) upfront to see if it is even possible to use that program ou want.
2. virtualBox. This requires a copy of Windows and you need to install Windows in a VBox. The CD will then autorun like from a normal Windows (since you install a normal Windows).

The other option is to forget about the Windows CD and focus on something from Ubuntu itself. There is a lot of educational stuff in our repositories and I doubt it *really* matters to a 5 year old what it is as long as it is fun and colourful ;-)

Comment: 100% agree: I know excellent educational stuff in repositories, unfortunately this CD was sold in the kindergarten and guess what: I'm the only parent using linux :) I'll try virtual box. Thank you!